# Python not printing all files in directory using os.listdir

Tags: python

[image]

```
import os


class Utilities:

    def __init__(self, filepath, archive, recursion):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.archive = archive
        self.recursion = recursion


    def filepath(self):
        filelist = []
        filename = os.listdir(self.filepath)
        for file in filename:
            filelist.append(file)
            print(filelist)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    u = Utilities('C:\_EmailDownloader', 'C:\_EmailDownloader\_OUT', 'C:\_EmailDownloader\_ARCHIVE')
    print(u.filepath)
```

Comment: Do you intend to have the `print` statement inside your for loop, instead of after the loop runs?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  ```u.filepath``` is a method.   You need to return the filelist in the ```filepath``` method.

Comment: And since `filename` is an iterator, you don't even need the for loop.  `filelist = list(filename)`.  And lastly, don't forget a `return` at the end, unless you really just want to print them.

Comment: Thank you both Frank and Ewong. You two are great! I didn't even realize I was calling the method filename as one of my __init__ class attributes. Its also great to know that I didn't even need that for loop!